# Populate table data from databse table on selecting a particuar item from drop down list?

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, ajax

I want to populate table data from database table "onchange" event for a dropdown list. Dropdown list itself contains data from that table but it only contains one column value. When user selects any of the item from that drop down list then all columns and its values should be displayed that belong to that particular value of selected item from drop down list.

Below is the code to only display dropdown list.

```
<?php
    include_once("session.php");
    include_once("functions.php");
    include_once("connection.php");

    $employername=$_SESSION["username"];
    $sql = "select job_name from job_info where username=$employername";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

?>

<div>
    <select name="ddljobname">
    <?php while($row=$result->fetch_assoc()){ ?>
        <option value="<?= $row['job_name'] ?>"><?= $row['job_name'] ?>         </option>
    <?php }?>
    </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 <select name="ddljobname" id="getdata">
    <?php while($row=$result->fetch_assoc()){ ?>
        <option value="<?= $row['job_name'] ?>"><?= $row['job_name'] ?>         </option>
    <?php }?>
    </select>
```

Onchange Function :

```
$('#getdata').change(function(){
var jobNum = $(this).val();
//call your ajax

});
```